# Forminator API - Get total value of submission data

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm attempting at pulling data from my Forminator submissions, but with no joy.Here's what I've got so far;

```
<?php

$form_id = 43;
$elem_id = 'currency-1';
$fields = Forminator_API::get_form_field( $form_id, $elem_id, $to_array );
var_dump(get_object_vars( $fields ));
```

currency-1, accepts a value from your input 100, 200 etc. What i'm trying to do is, add all those value together and show frontend.

Any advice is greatly appreachiate, i've spent around 4 hours looking at the api and not worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking at the wrong object, in order to pull those number you need to look at the submissions data which is

The below should give you a list of all the entries, you can loop through those and add the numbers together.

```
<?php
$form_id = 43;
$entries = Forminator_API::get_entries( $form_id );

foreach($entries as $key => $value){
   //add all values of currency-1 together
}

?>
```